# Use a ranged object for a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm searching for a certain header and saving it as a ranged object (FindEQ4). Now I want to use this header as a starting point for a dynamic ranged object. My question is, how can I get the information that Header 1 is in C5 and use it like `Set TestR = .Range("C" & 5 + x)`?

```
 Sub FindCopyPasteV3()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:FF")

        Dim FindEQ4 As Range
        Dim TestR As Range
        Dim x As Long

        Set FindEQ4 = .Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        'I'm looking for something like TestR = .Range("FindEQ4" + x)  
        'which works like Set TestR = .Range("C" & 5 + x) 

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `FindEQ4.Row` would allow you to see the row, and `FindEQ4.Column` would give the column.  If you use `Cells(row,column)` rather than range, you can find the appropriate column/row and use more appropriately, so you don't have to worry about converting a number to a letter (if you happen to not be in column "C")

Comment: I need to find the cell by searching for a certain text which is "Header 1" in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `.Column`or `.Row`properties for a `Range`object:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim FindEQ4  As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim StartColumn As Long
    Dim TestR As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set FindEQ4 = .Range("A1")
        StartRow = FindEQ4.Row + 1
        StartColumn = FindEQ4.Column
        Set TestR = .Cells(StartRow, StartColumn) 'A2
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Comment: This will give you the "coordinates" to your starting point, `FindEQ4`, so your starting point would be `Cells(FindEQ4.Row + 1, FindEQ4.Column)`

Comment: @JohnDemian check my edit, see if it's clearer for you now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Offset` property of the `Range` object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset

This returns a range that is offset from the original by the specified amount. The first parameter is the number of rows to offset by (positive downwards, negative upwards) and the second parameter is the number of columns to offset by (positive right, negative left).

so for example

`.Range("D7").offset(-3,2)` would represent "F4", 3 rows up and 2 columns to the right.

```
Sub FindCopyPasteV3()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:FF")

        Dim FindEQ4 As Range
        Dim TestR As Range
        Dim X As Long

        Set FindEQ4 = .Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)


        Set TestR = FindEQ4.Offset(X, 0) 'X rows down, same column



    End With

End Sub
```